# How to pass multiple parameters into Label Template?

Tags: umbraco7, archetypes

Is there a way to pass multiple parameters to Label Template function? It doesn't seem to work out of the box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use multiple fields. For example:

{{prop1}} - {{prop2}}

in the label template should work. Not sure about your custom function though. Looking at the docs here: https://github.com/kgiszewski/ArchetypeManual/blob/master/02%20-%20Configuration.md it looks like you can pass multiple arguments maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not going to work in my case, since I need to manipulate with two params inside a function. Basically I need to show/hide 1 param if another one has specific value. The arguments don't seem to work either, they support constants only, but don't support archetype properties, like: {arg1: prop1, arg2: prop2}.